# How do you convert bits into a different alphabet?

Tags: mathematical-foundations

I have forgotten how to do this. How do I figure out what the requirements are for a 128-bit string using a certain alphabet?

That is to say, I want to generate a UUID (128-bit) value, using only the 10 numbers for the alphabet. How many numbers do I need, and what is the general equation so I can figure this out for any alphabet of any size?

What is the equation for any n-bit value with any x-letter alphabet?

The way I do it is to guess and slowly iterate until I arrive at a close number. For powers of 10 it's easy:

```
Math.pow(2, 128)
3.402823669209385e+38
Math.pow(10, 39)
1e+39
```

For other numbers, it takes a little more guessing. Would love to know the equation for this.

Comment: $n$ bits can represent $2^n$ numbers. To represent that many numbers in base $b>1$ you will need $q$ digits, where $q$ satisfies $b^{q-1}<2^n\leq b^q$. Taking logarithm base $b$ you get $q-1<\log_b(2^n)\leq q$. This is (equivalent to) the definition of [the ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties). So, $q=\lceil \log_b(2^n)\rceil$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To estimate the number of decimal digits needed to represent a $128$ bit number you use logarithms to base $10$:

$128 \times \log_{10}(2) \approx 38.53$

so you need $39$ decimal digits to represent a $128$ bit number.

In a general, for an “alphabet” with $n$ symbols you need to find the value of $128 \times \log_n (2)$ and then round this up to the next whole number.